# SKVideoNode videoNodeWithFileNamed: crashes in iOS 8.4, fine in iOS 9

Tags: sprite-kit, ios8.4, skvideonode

In iOS 8.4, our game is crashing when trying to initialize an `SKVideoNode` via filename, works just fine in iOS 9. Apple documentation states that the following method is supported in 8.0 and later ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKVideoNode/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKVideoNode/videoNodeWithFileNamed:)):

```
SKVideoNode *introVideoNode = [SKVideoNode videoNodeWithFileNamed:@"intro.mp4"];
```

But crashes with:

```
+[SKVideoNode videoNodeWithFileNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to class
```

Now, everything works fine in both iOS 8 and 9 if I initialize with an `AVPlayer` instead:

```
SKVideoNode* introVideoNode = [[SKVideoNode alloc] initWithAVPlayer:player];
```

Has anyone else encountered this? Is this a SpriteKit bug with iOS 8?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried and it looks like it doesn't work on iOS8. It might be worth of filing a [radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/) about this.

Comment: @Whirlwind, thanks for the corroboration. I just filed a bug report with Apple.